# Python Multi-threading scraping, write data in csv file

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing, screen-scraping, pool

I use multiprocessing pool to multiply the speed of scraping and everything is okay, only I don't understand why python write every 30 rows the header of my csv, I know there is a link with the param of pool I entered but how can correct this behavior

```
def parse(url):

    dico = {i: '' for i in colonnes}

    r = requests.get("https://change.org" + url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    # sleep(2)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        # I scrape my data here
        ...
        pprint(dico)
        writer.writerow(dico)
    return dico

with open(lang + '/petitions_' + lang + '.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames= colonnes)
     writer.writeheader()
     with Pool(30) as p:
         p.map(parse, liens)
```

Someone can tell where put the 'writer.writerow(dico)' to avoid repetition of the header?
Thanks

Comment: What is in `colonnes`?

Comment: @rdas colonnes is the columns in french = ['id','titre','auteur','theme','date_de_publication','nbre_signatures','statut','lien']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file exists:

```
os.path.isfile('mydirectory/myfile.csv')
```

If it exists don't write the header again. Create a function(def...) for the header and another for data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "header" you are referring to comes from the `writer.writeheader()` line, not the `writer.writerow()` line.

Without a complete piece of your code, I can only assume that you have something like an outer loop that wraps around the `with open` block. So, every time your code enters the `with` block, a header line is printed, and then 30 lines of your scraped data (because of the pool size).